# Can a SurfaceView hold multiple ImageViews?

Tags: android

I was wondering if it was possible for a SurfaceView to hold multiple ImageView. Each ImageView should be able to move independently. Imagine a table of cards, where each card is to be moved. The cards (ImageViews) are to be added to the surfaceview dynamically. Any ideas? Tried researching it, but to no avail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Romain's answer hints at, you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of what SurfaceView is. Take a look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html). It's a View for drawing on, not to hold other Views (be they ImageViews or otherwise). You *can* draw images (including bitmaps) on it, but that's different from holding ImageViews. If you're looking to have a game with a bunch of cards, you probably want to find a tutorial on drawing with SurfaceViews. [This](http://www.droidnova.com/2d-sprite-animation-in-android,471.html) might be somewhere to start.

Answer (score 2):

A SurfaceView is a View, not a ViewGroup. Therefore, it cannot hold any ImageView at all :)